# How I can push into nested array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to push in to a nested, like this:

```js
[{
  "chatid": 10000414,
  "connected": true,
  "index": 0,
  "jsonedUser": {},
  "membership": "",
  "messages": [{
    "chatid": 10000414,
    "createdOn": "2018-10-29T16:50:44.4900000",
    "isArchive": false,
    "isNew": false,
    "message": "great",
    "messageid": 3,
    "sentby": {
      "id": 59,
      "name": "Ana"
    }
  }, {
    "chatid": 10000414,
    "createdOn": "2018-10-25T13:49:50.9900000",
    "isArchive": false,
    "isNew": false,
    "message": "hi",
    "messageid": 2,
    "sentby": {
      "id": 59,
      "name": "Ana"
    }
  }, {
    "chatid": 10000414,
    "createdOn": "2018-10-31T10:20:59.5000000",
    "isArchive": false,
    "isNew": false,
    "message": "hello there",
    "messageid": 1,
    "sentby": {
      "id": 91,
      "name": "Miliam"
    }
  }],
  "opened": true,
  "port": 10842,
}]
```

I try is push a similar object inside of messages [] I don't know what is the way for due it some one can help me please

I try push like this

```
var chat =  { chatid: 10000414, createdOn: "2018-10-29T16:50:44.4900000", isArchive: false, isNew: false, message: val, messageid: 3, sentby: {id:59, name:"betsynray"} }
    var newSingleChat = singleChat[0].messages.push(val);
```

but when I console the  newSingleChat is you show me '4'

Comment: probably something like: `theVariableHoldingTheOuterArray[indexOfObjectYouWant].messages.push(...)`

Comment: Push is returning the length of the messages array. If you console.log the the array after the operation you should be able to see the contents.

Comment: Your "i tried" block doesn't show where `val` and `singleChat` are defined.  `val` appears to be what you are putting as your message, so if you are trying to push that to your array of things, that doesn't match the structure of your other elements.  `chat` looks like the structure of your other elements, but you're not trying to push that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got [Array#push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) confused.

`.push()` will modify the original array and return the new length.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
var result = array.push("a");
// array: [1, 2, 3, "a"]
// result: 4
```

`.concat()` will return a new array based on the old array and the new values.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
var result = array.concat("a");
// array: [1, 2, 3]
// result: [1, 2, 3, "a"]
```

Comment: Sorry I am new in all this but how I can apply that into my example ?

Comment: I'm unclear where in the question you read that the issue was related to not updating the original array.  They *want* to update the original array

Comment: @Taplar if you read the final line, you'll see that Alfredo is checking the variable and seeing `4`, which is confusing him.

Comment: yes I want update the array inside messages:[] just that one

Comment: That doesn't mean he doesn't want to change the original array.

Comment: @Taplar true. In the OP's example, I'd say the next step would be to use `.concat()` and then `singleChat[0].messages = newSingleChat`. I think he was intending to do that which is why he was surprised that `newSingleChat` contained a number rather than a new array

Answer (score 0):

well thanks guys I solve it by using

```
var newSingleChat = singleChat[0].messages.concat(chat);
```

is work fine now thanks to all especial to @James Long

Comment: If someone answered the question you should accept their answer, not copy it and add your own.